# Importing a contract from GitHub

Tags: contract-development, library, import

I'm trying to import a contract from GitHub:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
pragma experimental "v0.5.0";

import "github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/library/stringUtils.sol";
```

However, it says, `Error: Could not find github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/library/stringUtils.sol from any sources;`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where you doing it from(Truffle,remix,mist,parity etc..) ? I tried your code in remix , it does work for me ?

Comment: I tried to compile it with Truffle 4.0.1. Do you believe it's a bug?

Answer (score 1):

The error is that solidity does not know the location of your import file(s).

Many solutions to this. Simple one, git clone the dapp_bin  and copy it to /usr/local

Now, invoke the compilation with

```
solc --optimize --combined-json abi,bin,interface github.com/ethereum/dapp_bin=/usr/local/dapp_bin <solidity file>
```

It includes a section to map the library to the section in your machine.

Comment: Well, of course, I can download it and use as a local file, that's not a problem. I thought maybe there was a way to skip this part. Looks like there isn't.